Wordpress post big content split into multiple pages
I was able to split content into multiple pages but its not properly breaking content to next page.
Issue image:

here is the javascript code
(function ($) {
$.fn.craftyslide = function (options) {
        // Defaults
        var defaults = {
            "width": '100%',
            "height": '100%',
            "pagination": true,
            "fadetime": 0,
            "delay": 0
        };

        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function () {

            // Vars
            var $this = $(this);
            var $slides = $this.find("pre");
            $slides.not(':first').hide();
            var numPages = $slides.length;

            // Pagination
            function paginate() {
                $this.append("<ol class='text-pagination craftyslide' />");

                var i = 1;
                $slides.each(function () {
                    $(this).attr("data-slide-id", "slide" + i);

                    $this.find(".text-pagination")
                        .append("<li data-slide-id='slide" + i + "' class='tp-page '></li>");
                    i++;
                });

                $this.find(".text-pagination li:first").addClass("active");
                $this.find(".text-pagination li:first").css("background", "#FEC932");
            }

            // Manual mode
            function manual() {
                var $pagination = $this.find(".text-pagination li");
                $pagination.click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var link = $(this);
                    var slideId = link.data('slide-id');
                    var $current = $this.find('pre[data-slide-id="' + slideId + '"]');
                    if ($current.is(":hidden")) {
                        $slides.fadeOut(options.fadetime);
                        $current.fadeIn(options.fadetime);
                        $pagination.removeClass("active");
                        $pagination.css("background", "");
                        $(this).addClass("active");
                        $(this).css("background", "#FEC932");
                    }
                });
            }

            $this.find("pre").css('height', options.height);

            if (numPages <= 1) {

            } else {
                paginate();
            }

            var singleLiWidth = $this.find(".text-pagination li").eq(0).outerWidth(true);
            var itemcount = $this.find(".text-pagination li").length;

            $this.find(".text-pagination").width(itemcount * singleLiWidth);

            manual();

        });
    };
})(jQuery);


//main JS code here
$(document).ready(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#target').show();
    var contentBox = $('#target');
    var words = contentBox.html().split('<br>'); // Split by whitespace characters
    // console.log(words);

    function paginate() {
        // Pagination logic
        var newPage = $('<pre class="text-page" />');
        contentBox.empty().append(newPage);
        var betterPageText = '';
        var pageNum = 0;
        var isNewPage = false;

        var lineHeight = parseInt(contentBox.css('line-height'), 10);
        var wantedHeight = contentBox.height() - lineHeight;

        for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            // console.log(words[i]);
            if (isNewPage) {
                betterPageText += ' ' + words[i];
                isNewPage = false;
            } else {
                betterPageText += ' ' + words[i];
            }

            newPage.html(betterPageText);
            if (newPage.height() >= wantedHeight) {
                pageNum++;
                if (pageNum > 0) {
                    betterPageText += ' '; // Add line break between pages
                }
                // console.log(betterPageText.trimStart());
                newPage.html(betterPageText.trimStart());
                if (i < words.length - 1) {
                    newPage.clone().insertBefore(newPage);
                }

                betterPageText = '';
                isNewPage = true;
            } else {
                newPage.html(betterPageText.trimStart());
            }
        }

        wantedHeight = "auto";

        // Apply the Craftyslide plugin to the contentBox
        contentBox.craftyslide({ height: wantedHeight });
    }

    // Call paginate() after the delay
    paginate();

    // Trigger resize event after a short delay
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(window).trigger('resize');
    }, 100); // Adjust the delay time as needed
}, 200); // Delay execution for 200 milliseconds

});
Can anyone help out with this ?
(function ($) {
$.fn.craftyslide = function (options) {
        // Defaults
        var defaults = {
            "width": '100%',
            "height": '100%',
            "pagination": true,
            "fadetime": 0,
            "delay": 0
        };

        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function () {

            // Vars
            var $this = $(this);
            var $slides = $this.find("pre");
            $slides.not(':first').hide();
            var numPages = $slides.length;

            // Pagination
            function paginate() {
                $this.append("<ol class='text-pagination craftyslide' />");

                var i = 1;
                $slides.each(function () {
                    $(this).attr("data-slide-id", "slide" + i);

                    $this.find(".text-pagination")
                        .append("<li data-slide-id='slide" + i + "' class='tp-page '></li>");
                    i++;
                });

                $this.find(".text-pagination li:first").addClass("active");
                $this.find(".text-pagination li:first").css("background", "#FEC932");
            }

            // Manual mode
            function manual() {
                var $pagination = $this.find(".text-pagination li");
                $pagination.click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var link = $(this);
                    var slideId = link.data('slide-id');
                    var $current = $this.find('pre[data-slide-id="' + slideId + '"]');
                    if ($current.is(":hidden")) {
                        $slides.fadeOut(options.fadetime);
                        $current.fadeIn(options.fadetime);
                        $pagination.removeClass("active");
                        $pagination.css("background", "");
                        $(this).addClass("active");
                        $(this).css("background", "#FEC932");
                    }
                });
            }

            $this.find("pre").css('height', options.height);

            if (numPages <= 1) {

            } else {
                paginate();
            }

            var singleLiWidth = $this.find(".text-pagination li").eq(0).outerWidth(true);
            var itemcount = $this.find(".text-pagination li").length;

            $this.find(".text-pagination").width(itemcount * singleLiWidth);

            manual();

        });
    };
})(jQuery);


//main JS code here
$(document).ready(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#target').show();
    var contentBox = $('#target');
    var words = contentBox.html().split('<br>'); // Split by whitespace characters
    // console.log(words);

    function paginate() {
        // Pagination logic
        var newPage = $('<pre class="text-page" />');
        contentBox.empty().append(newPage);
        var betterPageText = '';
        var pageNum = 0;
        var isNewPage = false;

        var lineHeight = parseInt(contentBox.css('line-height'), 10);
        var wantedHeight = contentBox.height() - lineHeight;

        for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            // console.log(words[i]);
            if (isNewPage) {
                betterPageText += ' ' + words[i];
                isNewPage = false;
            } else {
                betterPageText += ' ' + words[i];
            }

            newPage.html(betterPageText);
            if (newPage.height() >= wantedHeight) {
                pageNum++;
                if (pageNum > 0) {
                    betterPageText += ' '; // Add line break between pages
                }
                // console.log(betterPageText.trimStart());
                newPage.html(betterPageText.trimStart());
                if (i < words.length - 1) {
                    newPage.clone().insertBefore(newPage);
                }

                betterPageText = '';
                isNewPage = true;
            } else {
                newPage.html(betterPageText.trimStart());
            }
        }

        wantedHeight = "auto";

        // Apply the Craftyslide plugin to the contentBox
        contentBox.craftyslide({ height: wantedHeight });
    }

    // Call paginate() after the delay
    paginate();

    // Trigger resize event after a short delay
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(window).trigger('resize');
    }, 100); // Adjust the delay time as needed
}, 200); // Delay execution for 200 milliseconds

});
I have tried this code but still on some content its over lapping content on pagination
